# Browsers element set focus

Tags: c#

I am creating an application using C# webbrowser to navigate "www.messenger.com". While the webbrowser is processing, my application will run another process behind and resulting the "messenger.com" message textbox lost focus.

Can anyone tell me is there any way to enforce "messenger.com" message textbox to stay focus?

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
    if (el.GetAttribute("class") == "_5ywb")
    {
       el.Focus();
    }
```

I have try using the TagName but does not seen to work. So i wonder if there any alternative solution.

Thank You,

Comment: is the site `messenger.com` is under your control?

Comment: no, messenger.com is the messenger from facebook, i was trying to see if there anyway to focus the message textbox

Comment: _"my application will run another process behind"_ Can you describe this?  It sounds like it's another form opening or similar that's taking focus away from the webbrowser control, and therefore taking the focus away from the input?

Comment: @james Thorpe

Hi, it will open a on screen keyboard create from C#, so i guess you could said is another Window Form opening too.